# How to manage audio output on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-audiomanager

Problem: there is no internal speaker for Android wear. When my app rings, there is no sound unless user turn on speaker.

What I want to achieve: turn on external speaker if internal one is unavailable.

There could be two options:

1) detect internal speaker and decide whether to turn on speaker;

2) detect Android wearable and auto turn on speaker.

But there seem to be no APIs for either of them. Any idea?